# How can I save Kafka message Key in document for MongoDB Sink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Right now I have a MongoDB Sink and it saves the value of incoming AVRO messages correctly.
I need it to save the Kafka Message Key in the document.
I have tried `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key` in order to add the key to the value that is being saved, but this did nothing. It did work when using `ProvidedInKeyStrategy`, but I don't want my _id to be the Kafka message Key.

My configuration:

```
"config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongo1",
    "database": "mongodb",
    "collection": "sink",
    "topics": "topics.foo",

    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    
    "transforms": "hoistKey",

    "transforms.hoistKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key",
    "transforms.hoistKey.field":"kafkaKey"
  }
```

Kafka message schema:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Smoketest",
    "namespace": "some_namespace",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
    ]
}
```

Kafka key schema:

```
[
  {
    "type": "enum",
    "name": "EnvironmentType",
    "namespace": "some_namespace",
    "doc": "DEV",
    "symbols": [
      "Dev",
      "Test",
      "Accept",
      "Sandbox",
      "Prod"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Key",
    "namespace": "some_namespace",
    "doc": "The standard Key type that is used as key",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "conversation_id",
        "doc": "The first system producing an event sets this field",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "broker_key",
        "doc": "The key of the broker",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "user_id",
        "doc": "User identification",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "application",
        "doc": "The name of the application",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "environment",
        "doc": "The type of environment",
        "type": "type.EnvironmentType"        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the schema of your Kafka data?

Comment: @OneCricketeer added schemas to question

Comment: Avro `"type": "record"`should create a Connect Struct type. Do you have more of the stacktrace? What version of Kafka Connect are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Kafka version is 6.1.0, What else can I add?

Comment: Show more of the exception so we can tell where it's coming from, please

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updatet my configuration, I had removed some transformations for this question because I thought it wont make any difference, but apperently it does. With the previous configuration it did add the timestamp but it doesnt add the key.

Comment: You're still missing your stacktrace. It's not clear what transform is throwing the error. By the way, you can use FileStreamSink rather than Mongo to simply log out the Struct records to console or file. Debug by adding only one transform at a time until you have the format you expect in Mongo. (More specifically, your error has nothing to do with Mongo, so remove it while debugging)

Comment: @OneCricketeer The problem is that I don't get any errors anymore. I've checked all the logs too. HoistField$Key is not adding they key to the document. Can you give me 1 working example? Because I cannot find one. The only thing that I've seen working is providedInKeyStrategy but I want mongo to create its own key and not use the Kafka key.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have updatet my question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mongo key strategies, and those aren't used with FileStreamSink anyway for debugging purposes. For hoisting, your key schema cannot be an Avro record / struct itself; you can only hoist primitive values. For example, you can ExtractField$Key for the timestamp field, then you can Hoist on that float, which would effectively rename the key-name in the struct. In any case, Kafka records already have timestamps, so putting them as part of the key doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don’t understand what you are saying right now. You can forget the timestamp part, I think it is a bit confusing. My producer sends Kafka messages. These messages consist of a Kafka Key (avro), Kafka message (avro) and Kafka Headers (bytes). I want to save the Kafka Key and Kafka message in my sink. Hoistfield$key should extract Kafka Key and put it in a field but it doesn’t do anything. What other way can I save the Kafka Key in my sink?

Comment: "Doesn't do anything" because there's errors? Look at the the Connect server logs or /status endpoint... Your key schema is Struct. You can't hoist a Struct into another Struct.

Comment: If you want to "extract", then use ExtractField transform. Or use ksqlDB, for example, to explicitly select one or more fields and combine them since ExtractField won't be able to support building compound keys

Comment: @OneCricketeer https://github.com/f0xdx/kafka-connect-wrap-smt did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://github.com/f0xdx/kafka-connect-wrap-smt I can now wrap all the data from the kafka message into a single document to save in my mongodb sink.